# redis - fetch all hashes by pattern/prefix

Tags: redis

I have a hash pattern `websocket:socket:*`

```
$redis->hMSet('websocket:socket:1', ['block' => 9866]);
$redis->hMSet('websocket:socket:2', ['block' => 854]);
$redis->hMSet('websocket:socket:3', ['block' => 854]);
```

How can I fetch all hashes that matches pattern `websocket:socket:*` ??

Or what is the best way (performange wise) to keep track of a list of items?

Answer (score 3):

Redis does not provide search-by-value out of the box. You'll have to implement some kind of indexing yourself.

Read more about indexing in Redis at [Secondary indexing with Redis](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) (or use [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/)).

Comment: Ok, have changed my question a bit.. How can I now fetch all hashes with the underlaying key `block=854` ?

Comment: @clarkk there is no command to do that. You have two options outside of what Itamar suggested: 1) grab all of the hashes and filter out in the application, or 2) use a Lua script to filter out responses in Redis. T

Comment: @TheDude which solution would you suggest? :)

Comment: Depends on which fits your need. Lua scripts are useful, but they block all other commands from being executed.

Comment: @TheDude, ok thanks.. have updated my question.. I will follow your first suggestion.. But how to fetch all hashes that matches `websocket:socket:*` ?

Comment: You do use `KEYS` for that, but I advise against it for large databases (read more [here](https://redis.io/commands/keys). You can also have a set of the keys for websockets

Comment: No, you don't (use KEYS, or even SCAN). You *index* by value. Please please please pretty please RTFMs both of you :)